# Return value from jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to return some values from this:

[image]
and I have this in the console log:

[image]

How can I return the city, speed, etc.

Console.log(ui.item.speed) returns that item is undefined. It works perfectly in the above select function.

Comment: I'm guessing `console.log(ui.item.speed)` should have been `console.log(ui[0].speed)`.

Comment: Hello, you should never send images for code, instead you have two options: first you can use stackoverflow snippets feature or write your code in a formatted text way , please [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/tour/) about that

Comment: The `ui` parameter in `select:` is not the same as the `ui` parameter in `response` - response: is your response from the server, so ui is an array, while ui in the select: is the item you've selected.  If it works in one, doesn't mean it will work in the other.

Comment: The console log is what I'm getting when I do console.log(ui); .. I"m just not smart enough to select the city, state, etc in each one. I tried console.log(ul[0].city); and many other variations. Any suggestions? I think I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your requirement.  When you retrieve all possible answers from the server you want to get "*the*" city/speed - but there's a city/speed for each result, and you have 25 results.   This looks like an XY problem.   Can you detail exactly what you're trying to do at that point?  As there's probably an alternative approach.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)